# CDT does not exist in MySQL Timezones

Tags: mysql, timezone

I have recently updated MySql with Timezone information, using information mentioned here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html

The problem I am facing is that even though the database now has information on a lot of TimeZones, `CDT` is not one of them, and when I do a timezone conversion

using 
`SELECT CONVERT_TZ(displaytime,'GMT','CDT');` it returns null

Other conversions work though like 
`SELECT CONVERT_TZ(displaytime,'GMT','MET');` works well

I have checked that the timezone table does not contain information about CDT. But I am not sure how to fix it. Should I add this manually to the table? Should I use a different source to import timezone information?

Comment: The MySQL manual page you linked in your question actually contains the answer as well...

Comment: ```SELECT CONVERT_TZ(UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'+00:00','-06:00');``` This provides your required conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use time zone IDs that are [valid IANA TZDB identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  For US Central Time, use `'America/Chicago'`.

You should avoid using 3-character abbreviations for time zones, as only a few are in the TZDB, and in general they can be ambiguous (`CST` is also China Standard Time, Cuba Standard Time, etc...)

Also, While `UTC` and `GMT` will *work*, the fully qualified form is `Etc/UTC`.  In practice, you can use any of these.

Comment: Great. Adding to Matt's response, if someone is using Spring Boot use similar to this (in application.properties, say) - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=America/Chicago